# Problem with longtable headers

Tags: longtable

I have the following problem with a table in more than one page.

I am using `longtable`, I need that in all the pages appear the same caption and also in the first page after the caption the word continua, in the other pages after the caption the word `continuação`... and in the last page after the caption the word `conclusão`.

So, I used `\endfirsthead` for the first page of the table and it works fine. The caption of my table is two lines.

For the other pages I used `\endhead`, it works but like the caption name (two line) is no linebreak, it produces a table that exceeds the width of page.

I do not how to make for the last page. There is something like `\endlasthead`?

I hope some one can help me.

Thanks you in advance

There is an example of my document,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.0cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{format=hang,labelsep=endash,singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[LT]{format=hang,labelsep=endash,singlelinecheck=false}


\begin{document}

\section{INTRODUÇÃO}


\begin{flushleft}
\begin{thebibliography}{20}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Referências}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\bibitem{Basford85}BASFORD, K. E.; McLACHLAN, G. J. The mixture method of clustering applied to three-way data. \textbf{Journal of Classification}, New York, v.2, p.109-125, 1985.
\bibitem{Frutos14}FRUTOS, B. E. \textbf{Análisis de datos acoplados:} modelo T3-PCA. 371p. 2014. Tese (Doutorado em Estatística), Universidad de Salamanca, Salamanca. 2014.
\bibitem[Gauch(1988)]{Gauch88}GAUCH, H. Model selection and validation for yield trials with interaction. \textbf{Biometrics}, Washington, v.44, p.705-715, 1988.
\bibitem{Kiers01}KIERS, H. A. L.; MECHELEN, I. V.  Three-way component analysis: Priciples and illustrative application. \textbf{Psychological Methods}, Washington, v.6, p.84-110, 2001.
\bibitem{Kroonenberg08}KROONENBERG, P. M. \textbf{Applied Multiway Data Analysis}. New Jersey: Wiley-Interscience, 2008. 579p.
\bibitem{Kroonenberg83}\rule[0mm]{1.5cm}{0.1mm}. \textbf{Three-mode principal component analysis:} Theory and applications. Leiden: DSWO Press, 1983. 398p.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{flushleft}


\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{longtable}{lcccccccc}
\caption{Estimativas, [mudanças relativas] e (valores-$p$) dos parâmetros para os tempos baseline e follow-up considerando a cópula de Frank}\label{rel_Frank}\\
\multicolumn{9}{r}{{(continua)}}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Exclusão} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nenhuma} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_3$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_4$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_5$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_6$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_7$}\\\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{9}{l}
{\normalsize{\tablename} \thetable{} - {Estimativas, [mudanças relativas] e (valores-$p$) dos parâmetros para os tempos baseline e follow-up considerando a cópula de Frank}}\\
\multicolumn{9}{r}{{(continuação)}}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Exclusão} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nenhuma} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_3$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_4$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_5$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_6$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_7$}\\\hline
\endhead
                &       [-]         & [0,6896]  &       [2,2125]        &       [1,4052]        &        [2,922]        &       [2,1636]        &       [3,6039]        &       [4,4816]        \\
$\lambda$       &       6,5401  &       6,495   &       6,3954  &       6,4482  &       6,349   &        6,3986 &       6,3044  &       6,247   \\
                &(-) &  (-)         &   (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
                &       [-]         &   [-2,8814]       &       [0,8035]        &       [0,9697]        &        [-2,019]       &       [-1,5723]       &       [2,2684]        &       [-0,2182]       \\
$\beta_{01}$&   2,8875  &       2,9707  &       2,8643  &       2,8595  &       2,9458  &        2,9329 &       2,822   &       2,8938  \\
                &       ($< 0,01$)          &   ($< 0,01$)          &   ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\
                &       [-]         &   [56,7481]       &       [48,0554]       &       [-39,3183]      &        [90,5407]      &       [18,3417]       &       [8,5782]        &       [49,2792]       \\
$\beta_{111}$   &       0,0882  &       0,0381  &       0,0458  &       0,1228  &       0,0083   &      0,072   &       0,0806  &       0,0447  \\
                &       (0,5789)        &       (0,8054)        &       (0,7806)        &       (0,4396)         &      (0,9589)        &       (0,6468)        &       (0,6223)        &       (0,7846)        \\\hline
                &       [-]         &   [22,2073]       &       [41,0150]       &       [-76,9871]      &        [56,0598]      &       [-45,5961]      &       [-41,0043]      &       [-18,4032]      \\
$\beta_{121}$   &       0,1117  &       0,0869  &       0,0659  &       0,1977  &       0,0491   &      0,1627  &       0,1575  &       0,1323  \\
                &       (0,6888)        &       (0,7482)        &       (0,8199)        &       (0,4810)         &      (0,8621)        &       (0,555) &       (0,5859)        &       (0,6442)        \\\hline
                &       [-]     &       [11,7796]       &       [-15,8828]      &       [-40,2128]      &        [0,5080]       &       [-23,5549]&     [-65,3486]      &       [-45,5596]      \\
$\beta_{21}$    &       0,2284  &       0,2015  &       0,2646  &       0,3202  &       0,2272   &      0,2822  &       0,3776  &       0,3324  \\
               &        (0,4133)        &       (0,4698)        &       (0,3513)        &       (0,2488)         &      (0,4254)        &       (0,3128)        &       (0,1773)        &       (0,2424)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [35,3161]       &       [-6,3366]       &       [-20,7819]      &        [28,2217]      &       [15,5278]       &       [-32,1313]      &       [-0,3517]       \\
$\beta_{311}$   &       -0,145  &       -0,0938 &       -0,1542 &       -0,1752 &       -0,1041  &      -0,1225 &       -0,1916 &       -0,1455 \\
               &        (0,4463)        &       (0,6125)        &       (0,4291)        &       (0,364) &        (0,5879)       &       (0,5201)        &       (0,3312)        &       (0,4615)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-584,6088]     &       [0,6058]        &       [677,5275]      &        [-572,6303]    &       [38,123]        &       [773,8077]      &       [219,3328]      \\
$\beta_{321}$  &        0,0117  &       0,0802  &       0,0117  &       -0,0677 &       0,0788   &      0,0073  &       -0,0790 &       -0,0140 \\
               &        (0,9664)        &       (0,7653)        &       (0,9678)        &       (0,8091)         &      (0,7800)        &       (0,9791)        &       (0,7850)        &       (0,9614)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-43,6475]      &       [-4,7513]       &       [24,1401]       &        [-42,4545]     &       [-17,212]       &       [23,8471]       &       [-8,6862]       \\
$\beta_{41}$    &       0,1433  &       0,2059  &       0,1501  &       0,1087  &       0,2042   &      0,168   &       0,1092  &       0,1558  \\
               &        (0,3855)        &       (0,2016)        &       (0,3724)        &       (0,5109)         &      (0,2195)        &       (0,3066)        &       (0,5158)        &       (0,3563)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [0,1527]        &       [-5,7376]       &       [-7,9006]       &        [-4,2475]      &       [-5,8202]       &       [-15,8384]      &       [-12,8209]      \\
$\beta_{511}$   &       -0,2423 &       -0,2419 &       -0,2562 &       -0,2614 &       -0,2526  &      -0,2564 &       -0,2806 &       -0,2733 \\
               &        (0,0599)        &       (0,0539)        &       (0,0499)        &       (0,0460)         &      (0,0489)        &       (0,0459)        &       (0,0342)        &       (0,0375)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [48,2997]       &       [-9,8648]       &       [2,8861]        &        [31,9274]      &       [42,2839]       &       [-8,4832]       &       [22,0012]       \\
$\beta_{521}$   &       0,4393  &       0,2271  &       0,4827  &       0,4267  &       0,2991   &      0,2536  &       0,4766  &       0,3427  \\
               &        (0,0323)        &       (0,2804)        &       (0,0201)        &       (0,0386)         &      (0,1773)        &       (0,2403)        &       (0,0227)        &       (0,1308)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [85,5329]       &       [18,4501]       &       [27,7082]       &        [92,3940]      &       [100,4204]      &       [43,6462]       &       [103,0815]      \\
$\beta_{611}$   &       0,1012  &       0,0146  &       0,0826  &       0,0732  &       0,0077   &      -0,0004 &       0,057   &       -0,0031 \\
               &        (0,7714)        &       (0,9655)        &       (0,8168)        &       (0,8370)         &      (0,9825)        &       (0,9990)        &       (0,8753)        &       (0,9931)\\ \hline
               &        [-]     &       [14,6667]       &       [0,7533]        &       [1,9729]        &        [13,1646]      &       [14,6645]       &       [2,0605]        &       [11,9252]       \\
$\beta_{621}$   &       0,4567  &       0,3897  &       0,4532  &       0,4477  &       0,3966   &      0,3897  &       0,4473  &       0,4022  \\
               &        (0,1768)        &       (0,2365)        &       (0,1916)        &       (0,1971)         &      (0,2470)        &       (0,2522)        &       (0,2087)        &       (0,2567)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-12,7027]      &       [-8,4377]       &       [36,3965]       &        [-17,0321]     &       [19,1710]       &       [28,2682]       &       [18,3447]       \\
$\beta_{71}$    &       0,1086  &       0,1224  &       0,1177  &       0,069   &       0,1271   &      0,0877  &       0,0779  &       0,0886  \\
               &        (0,4648)        &       (0,3886)        &       (0,4360)        &       (0,6426)         &      (0,3836)        &       (0,5422)        &       (0,6070)        &       (0,5499)        \\
               &        [-]     &       [17,5383]       &       [1,4407]        &       [-0,5275]       &        [17,5213]      &       [15,0539]       &       [-1,0550]       &       [12,6773]       \\
$\beta_{811}$   &       0,1763  &       0,1454  &       0,1738  &       0,1772  &       0,1454   &      0,1498  &       0,1782  &       0,154   \\
               &        (0,1579)        &       (0,2336)        &       (0,1731)        &       (0,1599)         &      (0,2481)        &       (0,2288)        &       (0,1656)        &       (0,2304)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [1,0655]        &       [1,0209]        &       [-1,7617]       &        [2,7033]       &       [-0,4237]       &       [-1,6527]       &       [0,4931]        \\
$\beta_{821}$   &       0,4036  &       0,3993  &       0,3995  &       0,4107  &       0,3927   &      0,4053  &       0,4103  &       0,4016  \\
               &        (0,006) &       (0,0056)        &       (0,0073)        &       (0,0050)        &        (0,0077)       &       (0,0052)        &       (0,0057)        &       (0,0067)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [12,3705]       &       [-71,9775]      &       [127,1981]      &        [-46,5702]     &       [117,4943]      &       [68,9857]       &       [70,8474]       \\
$\beta_{911}$   &       0,0873  &       0,0765  &       0,1502  &       -0,0238 &       0,128    &      -0,0153 &       0,0271  &       0,0255  \\
               &        (0,4921)        &       (0,5372)        &       (0,2607)        &       (0,8547)         &      (0,3297)        &       (0,9055)        &       (0,8374)        &       (0,8472)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-4,3624]       &       [-25,0195]      &       [-3,3451]       &        [-23,0903]     &       [-6,1816]       &       [-33,0752]      &       [-30,0600]      \\
$\beta_{921}$   &       0,2182  &       0,2278  &       0,2728  &       0,2255  &       0,2686   &      0,2317  &       0,2904  &       0,2838  \\
               &        (0,0173)        &       (0,0103)        &       (0,0047)        &       (0,0149)         &      (0,0043)        &       (0,0103)        &       (0,0027)        &       (0,0031)        \\\hline
              & [-]     &       [-13,2866]      &       [9,7224]        &       [12,3011]       &        [-4,2000]      &       [-1,2793]       &       [24,6732]       &       [12,0985]       \\
$\beta_{101}$   &       -0,3948 &       -0,4472 &       -0,3564 &       -0,3462 &       -0,4113  &      -0,3998 &       -0,2974 &       -0,347  \\
               &        ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)       &      ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [91,6717]       &       [-67,7171]      &       [-58,2826]      &        [17,6614]      &       [24,5902]       &       [-138,7507]     &       [-71,9523]      \\
$\beta_{11}$    &       -0,0575 &       -0,0048 &       -0,0964 &       -0,091  &       -0,0473  &      -0,0433 &       -0,1372 &       -0,0988 \\
                &       (0,4960)        &       (0,9552)        &       (0,2675)        &       (0,2883)         &      (0,5994)        &       (0,6245)        &       (0,1166)        &       (0,2852)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-1,7591]       &       [-0,1083]       &       [0,7552]        &        [-1,7679]      &       [-0,6439]       &       [0,8400]        &       [-0,5151]       \\
$\beta_{02}$    &       3,4165  &       3,4766  &       3,4202  &       3,3907  &       3,4769   &      3,4385  &       3,3878  &       3,4341  \\
               &        ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)       &      ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-165,2968]     &       [-116,7258]     &       [125,3916]      &        [-247,8495]    &       [-45,3920]      &       [12,9270]       &       [-114,5733]     \\
$\beta_{112}$   &       -0,0502 &       -0,1331 &       -0,1087 &       0,0127  &       -0,1745  &      -0,0729 &       -0,0437 &       -0,1077 \\
               &        (0,7924)        &       (0,4748)        &       (0,5709)        &       (0,9458)         &      (0,3579)        &       (0,6963)        &       (0,8146)        &       (0,5681)        \\ \hline
               &        [-]     &       [17,9331]       &       [30,9663]       &       [-81,7249]      &        [44,5081]      &       [-53,2645]      &       [-57,1757]      &       [-35,2755]      \\
$\beta_{122}$   &       0,1608  &       0,132   &       0,111   &       0,2923  &       0,0892   &      0,2465  &       0,2528  &       0,2176  \\
               &        (0,5911)        &       (0,6464)        &       (0,7162)        &       (0,3179)         &      (0,7638)        &       (0,3905)        &       (0,3909)        &       (0,4578)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-13,5716]      &       [31,0160]       &       [100,3102]      &        [6,4886]       &       [74,0291]       &       [149,3235]      &       [115,0191]      \\
$\beta_{22}$    &       -0,1228 &       -0,1395 &       -0,0847 &       0,0004  &       -0,1149  &      -0,0319 &       0,0606  &       0,0184  \\
               &        (0,6843)        &       (0,6469)        &       (0,7761)        &       (0,9989)         &      (0,7040)        &       (0,9125)        &       (0,8249)        &       (0,9481)        \\\hline
              & [-]     &       [39,2112]       &       [-4,8815]       &       [-22,6829]      &        [30,9879]      &       [16,1972]       &       [-31,8051]      &       [0,3957]        \\
$\beta_{312}$   &       -0,2325 &       -0,1413 &       -0,2439 &       -0,2853 &       -0,1605  &      -0,1949 &       -0,3065 &       -0,2316 \\
             &  (0,2806)        &       (0,5029)        &       (0,2570)        &       (0,1804)        &        (0,4553)       &       (0,3623)        &       (0,1471)        &       (0,2847)        \\\hline
             &  [-]     &       [63,3405]       &       [-4,4498]       &       [-64,9917]      &        [54,1403]      &       [0,4386]        &       [-78,0729]      &       [-23,6573]      \\
$\beta_{322}$   &       -0,2052 &       -0,0752 &       -0,2143 &       -0,3385 &       -0,0941  &      -0,2043 &       -0,3654 &       -0,2537 \\
            &   (0,5233)        &       (0,8104)        &       (0,5133)        &       (0,2872)        &        (0,7730)       &       (0,5239)        &       (0,2571)        &       (0,4418)        \\\hline
            &   [-]     &       [59,6874]       &       [1,7870]        &       [-34,0306]      &        [52,7582]      &       [21,7487]       &       [-36,9651]      &       [6,2874]        \\
$\beta_{42}$    &       -0,1673 &       -0,0675 &       -0,1643 &       -0,2243 &       -0,079   &      -0,1309 &       -0,2292 &       -0,1568 \\
           &    (0,3622)        &       (0,7098)        &       (0,3721)        &       (0,2111)        &        (0,6689)       &       (0,4727)        &       (0,1980)        &       (0,3928)        \\\hline
           &    [-]     &       [1,4721]        &       [-8,0926]       &       [-29,5914]      &        [-1,9366]      &       [-20,1763]      &       [-45,0051]      &       [-31,7090]      \\
$\beta_{512}$   &       -0,127  &       -0,1252 &       -0,1373 &       -0,1646 &       -0,1295  &      -0,1527 &       -0,1842 &       -0,1673 \\
           &    (0,3863)        &       (0,3857)        &       (0,3374)        &       (0,2570)        &        (0,3611)       &       (0,2886)        &       (0,1907)        &       (0,2351)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [100,9776]      &       [-25,4129]      &       [10,5148]       &       [65,7938]        &      [95,2973]       &       [-17,8592]      &       [52,6902]       \\
$\beta_{522}$   &       0,3009  &       -0,0029 &       0,3774  &       0,2693  &       0,1029   &      0,0142  &       0,3547  &       0,1424  \\
        &       (0,2084)        &       (0,9904)        &       (0,1105)        &       (0,2515)        &        (0,6821)       &       (0,9538)        &       (0,1248)        &       (0,5706)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [73,3693]       &       [22,6689]       &       [20,0987]       &       [81,5366]        &      [79,7052]       &       [44,7341]       &       [88,3361]       \\
$\beta_{612}$   &       0,1642  &       0,0437  &       0,127   &       0,1312  &       0,0303   &      0,0333  &       0,0907  &       0,0192  \\
        &       (0,6651)        &       (0,9061)        &       (0,7336)        &       (0,7251)        &        (0,9348)       &       (0,9283)        &       (0,8026)        &       (0,9583)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [22,3382]       &       [5,0190]        &       [4,3064]        &       [22,5685]        &      [22,5925]       &       [10,1339]       &       [22,8972]       \\
$\beta_{622}$   &       0,4168  &       0,3237  &       0,3959  &       0,3989  &       0,3228   &      0,3227  &       0,3746  &       0,3214  \\
        &       (0,2509)        &       (0,3606)        &       (0,2684)        &       (0,2650)        &        (0,3629)       &       (0,3627)        &       (0,2828)        &       (0,3607)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [-29,7453]      &       [-10,2254]      &       [50,1416]       &       [-35,2851]       &      [15,1650]       &       [43,0284]       &       [16,0191]       \\
$\beta_{72}$    &       0,1300  &       0,1686  &       0,1433  &       0,0648  &       0,1758   &      0,1103  &       0,0740  &       0,1092  \\
        &       (0,4488)        &       (0,3087)        &       (0,4027)        &       (0,7041)        &        (0,2922)       &       (0,5092)        &       (0,6622)        &       (0,5159)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [100,3907]      &       [22,2708]       &       [-32,6317]      &       [113,4617]       &      [60,5910]       &       [-25,7052]&     [56,5706]       \\
$\beta_{812}$   &       0,0469  &       -0,0002 &       0,0365  &       0,0623  &       -0,0063  &      0,0185  &       0,0590  &       0,0204  \\
        &       (0,7473)        &       (0,9990)        &       (0,8025)        &       (0,6613)        &        (0,9653)       &       (0,8962)        &       (0,6771)        &       (0,8868)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [10,5188]       &       [-26,1467]      &       [69,5096]       &       [-27,8880]       &      [67,4813]       &       [62,8643]       &       [44,2431]       \\
$\beta_{822}$   &       -0,0366 &       -0,0327 &       -0,0461 &       -0,0112 &       -0,0468  &      -0,0119 &       -0,0136 &       -0,0204 \\
        &       (0,8277)        &       (0,8437)        &       (0,7816)        &       (0,9456)        &        (0,7779)       &       (0,9418)        &       (0,9328)        &       (0,8998)        \\
\hline
        &       [-]     &       [476,2726]      &       [-4989,7926]    &       [8406,4907]     &        [-3793,2938]   &       [7532,8037]     &       [4282,1708]     &       [4042,7417]     \\
$\beta_{912}$   &       0,0019  &       -0,007  &       0,0945  &       -0,1542 &       0,0723   &      -0,138  &       -0,0776 &       -0,0732 \\
        &       (0,9897)        &       (0,9607)        &       (0,5258)        &       (0,2789)        &        (0,6241)       &       (0,3322)        &       (0,5849)        &       (0,6095)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [-16,7772]      &       [-33,7041]      &       [0,3092]        &       [-41,4144]       &      [-14,0791]      &       [-38,3522]      &       [-43,4143]      \\
$\beta_{922}$   &       0,2005  &       0,2342  &       0,2681  &       0,1999  &       0,2836   &      0,2287  &       0,2774  &       0,2876  \\
        &       (0,0477)        &       (0,0180)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0455)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0206)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [-26,3750]      &       [14,1763]       &       [23,2927]       &       [-12,2019]       &      [-3,3005]       &       [41,6558]       &       [17,4443]       \\
$\beta_{102}$   &       -0,3069 &       -0,3879 &       -0,2634 &       -0,2354 &       -0,3444  &      -0,3171 &       -0,1791 &       -0,2534 \\
        &       (0,0173)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0379)        &       (0,0702)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0149)        &       (0,1596)        &       (0,0551)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [162,8640]      &       [-102,1359]     &       [-84,1793]      &       [44,1015]        &      [59,6800]       &       [-199,2437]     &       [-85,6125]      \\
$\beta_{12}$    &       -0,0504 &       0,0317  &       -0,1018 &       -0,0928 &       -0,0282  &      -0,0203 &       -0,1508 &       -0,0935 \\
        &       (0,6016)        &       (0,7544)        &       (0,2903)        &       (0,3263)        &        (0,7857)       &       (0,8420)        &       (0,1051)        &       (0,3596)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [2,4220]        &       [-3,4669]       &       [-3,0767]       &       [-1,9391]        &      [-1,3636]       &       [-6,2017]       &       [-5,9081]       \\
$\sigma_1$      &       0,5178  &       0,5052  &       0,5357  &       0,5337  &       0,5278  &        0,5248 &       0,5499  &       0,5484  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [1,8267]        &       [0,9849]        &       [2,0193]        &       [1,4232]         &      [2,2265]        &       [4,1780]        &       [2,9235]        \\
$\sigma_2$      &       0,5452  &       0,5353  &       0,5399  &       0,5342  &       0,5375  &        0,5331 &       0,5225  &       0,5293  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [2,7645]        &       [-4,6144]       &       [-4,0787]       &       [-2,6912]        &      [-1,9713]       &       [-8,6345]       &       [-8,0444]       \\
$\alpha_1$      &       0,4779  &       0,4646  &       0,4999  &       0,4973  &       0,4907  &        0,4873 &       0,5191  &       0,5163  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [2,2435]        &       [0,8065]        &       [2,3235]        &       [1,4781]         &      [2,6067]        &       [4,3202]        &       [2,9517]        \\
$\alpha_2$      &       0,4377  &       0,4279  &       0,4342  &       0,4275  &       0,4312  &        0,4263 &       0,4188  &       0,4248  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{scriptsize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution only (not for the last page (yet?))

It's possible to use `\caption*` again in the `\endhead` part of the description. This won't increase the table counter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.0cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{format=hang,labelsep=endash,singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[LT]{format=hang,labelsep=endash,singlelinecheck=false}


\begin{document}

\section{INTRODUÇÃO}


\begin{flushleft}
\begin{thebibliography}{20}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Referências}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\bibitem{Basford85}BASFORD, K. E.; McLACHLAN, G. J. The mixture method of clustering applied to three-way data. \textbf{Journal of Classification}, New York, v.2, p.109-125, 1985.
\bibitem{Frutos14}FRUTOS, B. E. \textbf{Análisis de datos acoplados:} modelo T3-PCA. 371p. 2014. Tese (Doutorado em Estatística), Universidad de Salamanca, Salamanca. 2014.
\bibitem[Gauch(1988)]{Gauch88}GAUCH, H. Model selection and validation for yield trials with interaction. \textbf{Biometrics}, Washington, v.44, p.705-715, 1988.
\bibitem{Kiers01}KIERS, H. A. L.; MECHELEN, I. V.  Three-way component analysis: Priciples and illustrative application. \textbf{Psychological Methods}, Washington, v.6, p.84-110, 2001.
\bibitem{Kroonenberg08}KROONENBERG, P. M. \textbf{Applied Multiway Data Analysis}. New Jersey: Wiley-Interscience, 2008. 579p.
\bibitem{Kroonenberg83}\rule[0mm]{1.5cm}{0.1mm}. \textbf{Three-mode principal component analysis:} Theory and applications. Leiden: DSWO Press, 1983. 398p.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{flushleft}


\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{longtable}{l*{9}c}
\caption{Estimativas, [mudanças relativas] e (valores-$p$) dos parâmetros para os tempos baseline e follow-up considerando a cópula de Frank}\label{rel_Frank}\\
\multicolumn{9}{r}{{(continua)}}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Exclusão} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nenhuma} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_3$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_4$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_5$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_6$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_7$}\\\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption*{Estimativas, [mudanças relativas] e (valores-$p$) dos parâmetros para os tempos baseline e follow-up considerando a cópula de Frank}\\
\multicolumn{9}{r}{{(continuação)}}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Exclusão} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nenhuma} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_3$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_4$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_5$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_6$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_7$}\\\hline
\endhead
                &       [-]         & [0,6896]  &       [2,2125]        &       [1,4052]        &        [2,922]        &       [2,1636]        &       [3,6039]        &       [4,4816]        \\
$\lambda$       &       6,5401  &       6,495   &       6,3954  &       6,4482  &       6,349   &        6,3986 &       6,3044  &       6,247   \\
                &(-) &  (-)         &   (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
                &       [-]         &   [-2,8814]       &       [0,8035]        &       [0,9697]        &        [-2,019]       &       [-1,5723]       &       [2,2684]        &       [-0,2182]       \\
$\beta_{01}$&   2,8875  &       2,9707  &       2,8643  &       2,8595  &       2,9458  &        2,9329 &       2,822   &       2,8938  \\
                &       ($< 0,01$)          &   ($< 0,01$)          &   ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\
                &       [-]         &   [56,7481]       &       [48,0554]       &       [-39,3183]      &        [90,5407]      &       [18,3417]       &       [8,5782]        &       [49,2792]       \\
$\beta_{111}$   &       0,0882  &       0,0381  &       0,0458  &       0,1228  &       0,0083   &      0,072   &       0,0806  &       0,0447  \\
                &       (0,5789)        &       (0,8054)        &       (0,7806)        &       (0,4396)         &      (0,9589)        &       (0,6468)        &       (0,6223)        &       (0,7846)        \\\hline
                &       [-]         &   [22,2073]       &       [41,0150]       &       [-76,9871]      &        [56,0598]      &       [-45,5961]      &       [-41,0043]      &       [-18,4032]      \\
$\beta_{121}$   &       0,1117  &       0,0869  &       0,0659  &       0,1977  &       0,0491   &      0,1627  &       0,1575  &       0,1323  \\
                &       (0,6888)        &       (0,7482)        &       (0,8199)        &       (0,4810)         &      (0,8621)        &       (0,555) &       (0,5859)        &       (0,6442)        \\\hline
                &       [-]     &       [11,7796]       &       [-15,8828]      &       [-40,2128]      &        [0,5080]       &       [-23,5549]&     [-65,3486]      &       [-45,5596]      \\
$\beta_{21}$    &       0,2284  &       0,2015  &       0,2646  &       0,3202  &       0,2272   &      0,2822  &       0,3776  &       0,3324  \\
               &        (0,4133)        &       (0,4698)        &       (0,3513)        &       (0,2488)         &      (0,4254)        &       (0,3128)        &       (0,1773)        &       (0,2424)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [35,3161]       &       [-6,3366]       &       [-20,7819]      &        [28,2217]      &       [15,5278]       &       [-32,1313]      &       [-0,3517]       \\
$\beta_{311}$   &       -0,145  &       -0,0938 &       -0,1542 &       -0,1752 &       -0,1041  &      -0,1225 &       -0,1916 &       -0,1455 \\
               &        (0,4463)        &       (0,6125)        &       (0,4291)        &       (0,364) &        (0,5879)       &       (0,5201)        &       (0,3312)        &       (0,4615)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-584,6088]     &       [0,6058]        &       [677,5275]      &        [-572,6303]    &       [38,123]        &       [773,8077]      &       [219,3328]      \\
$\beta_{321}$  &        0,0117  &       0,0802  &       0,0117  &       -0,0677 &       0,0788   &      0,0073  &       -0,0790 &       -0,0140 \\
               &        (0,9664)        &       (0,7653)        &       (0,9678)        &       (0,8091)         &      (0,7800)        &       (0,9791)        &       (0,7850)        &       (0,9614)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-43,6475]      &       [-4,7513]       &       [24,1401]       &        [-42,4545]     &       [-17,212]       &       [23,8471]       &       [-8,6862]       \\
$\beta_{41}$    &       0,1433  &       0,2059  &       0,1501  &       0,1087  &       0,2042   &      0,168   &       0,1092  &       0,1558  \\
               &        (0,3855)        &       (0,2016)        &       (0,3724)        &       (0,5109)         &      (0,2195)        &       (0,3066)        &       (0,5158)        &       (0,3563)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [0,1527]        &       [-5,7376]       &       [-7,9006]       &        [-4,2475]      &       [-5,8202]       &       [-15,8384]      &       [-12,8209]      \\
$\beta_{511}$   &       -0,2423 &       -0,2419 &       -0,2562 &       -0,2614 &       -0,2526  &      -0,2564 &       -0,2806 &       -0,2733 \\
               &        (0,0599)        &       (0,0539)        &       (0,0499)        &       (0,0460)         &      (0,0489)        &       (0,0459)        &       (0,0342)        &       (0,0375)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [48,2997]       &       [-9,8648]       &       [2,8861]        &        [31,9274]      &       [42,2839]       &       [-8,4832]       &       [22,0012]       \\
$\beta_{521}$   &       0,4393  &       0,2271  &       0,4827  &       0,4267  &       0,2991   &      0,2536  &       0,4766  &       0,3427  \\
               &        (0,0323)        &       (0,2804)        &       (0,0201)        &       (0,0386)         &      (0,1773)        &       (0,2403)        &       (0,0227)        &       (0,1308)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [85,5329]       &       [18,4501]       &       [27,7082]       &        [92,3940]      &       [100,4204]      &       [43,6462]       &       [103,0815]      \\
$\beta_{611}$   &       0,1012  &       0,0146  &       0,0826  &       0,0732  &       0,0077   &      -0,0004 &       0,057   &       -0,0031 \\
               &        (0,7714)        &       (0,9655)        &       (0,8168)        &       (0,8370)         &      (0,9825)        &       (0,9990)        &       (0,8753)        &       (0,9931)\\ \hline
               &        [-]     &       [14,6667]       &       [0,7533]        &       [1,9729]        &        [13,1646]      &       [14,6645]       &       [2,0605]        &       [11,9252]       \\
$\beta_{621}$   &       0,4567  &       0,3897  &       0,4532  &       0,4477  &       0,3966   &      0,3897  &       0,4473  &       0,4022  \\
               &        (0,1768)        &       (0,2365)        &       (0,1916)        &       (0,1971)         &      (0,2470)        &       (0,2522)        &       (0,2087)        &       (0,2567)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-12,7027]      &       [-8,4377]       &       [36,3965]       &        [-17,0321]     &       [19,1710]       &       [28,2682]       &       [18,3447]       \\
$\beta_{71}$    &       0,1086  &       0,1224  &       0,1177  &       0,069   &       0,1271   &      0,0877  &       0,0779  &       0,0886  \\
               &        (0,4648)        &       (0,3886)        &       (0,4360)        &       (0,6426)         &      (0,3836)        &       (0,5422)        &       (0,6070)        &       (0,5499)        \\
               &        [-]     &       [17,5383]       &       [1,4407]        &       [-0,5275]       &        [17,5213]      &       [15,0539]       &       [-1,0550]       &       [12,6773]       \\
$\beta_{811}$   &       0,1763  &       0,1454  &       0,1738  &       0,1772  &       0,1454   &      0,1498  &       0,1782  &       0,154   \\
               &        (0,1579)        &       (0,2336)        &       (0,1731)        &       (0,1599)         &      (0,2481)        &       (0,2288)        &       (0,1656)        &       (0,2304)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [1,0655]        &       [1,0209]        &       [-1,7617]       &        [2,7033]       &       [-0,4237]       &       [-1,6527]       &       [0,4931]        \\
$\beta_{821}$   &       0,4036  &       0,3993  &       0,3995  &       0,4107  &       0,3927   &      0,4053  &       0,4103  &       0,4016  \\
               &        (0,006) &       (0,0056)        &       (0,0073)        &       (0,0050)        &        (0,0077)       &       (0,0052)        &       (0,0057)        &       (0,0067)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [12,3705]       &       [-71,9775]      &       [127,1981]      &        [-46,5702]     &       [117,4943]      &       [68,9857]       &       [70,8474]       \\
$\beta_{911}$   &       0,0873  &       0,0765  &       0,1502  &       -0,0238 &       0,128    &      -0,0153 &       0,0271  &       0,0255  \\
               &        (0,4921)        &       (0,5372)        &       (0,2607)        &       (0,8547)         &      (0,3297)        &       (0,9055)        &       (0,8374)        &       (0,8472)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-4,3624]       &       [-25,0195]      &       [-3,3451]       &        [-23,0903]     &       [-6,1816]       &       [-33,0752]      &       [-30,0600]      \\
$\beta_{921}$   &       0,2182  &       0,2278  &       0,2728  &       0,2255  &       0,2686   &      0,2317  &       0,2904  &       0,2838  \\
               &        (0,0173)        &       (0,0103)        &       (0,0047)        &       (0,0149)         &      (0,0043)        &       (0,0103)        &       (0,0027)        &       (0,0031)        \\\hline
              & [-]     &       [-13,2866]      &       [9,7224]        &       [12,3011]       &        [-4,2000]      &       [-1,2793]       &       [24,6732]       &       [12,0985]       \\
$\beta_{101}$   &       -0,3948 &       -0,4472 &       -0,3564 &       -0,3462 &       -0,4113  &      -0,3998 &       -0,2974 &       -0,347  \\
               &        ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)       &      ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [91,6717]       &       [-67,7171]      &       [-58,2826]      &        [17,6614]      &       [24,5902]       &       [-138,7507]     &       [-71,9523]      \\
$\beta_{11}$    &       -0,0575 &       -0,0048 &       -0,0964 &       -0,091  &       -0,0473  &      -0,0433 &       -0,1372 &       -0,0988 \\
                &       (0,4960)        &       (0,9552)        &       (0,2675)        &       (0,2883)         &      (0,5994)        &       (0,6245)        &       (0,1166)        &       (0,2852)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-1,7591]       &       [-0,1083]       &       [0,7552]        &        [-1,7679]      &       [-0,6439]       &       [0,8400]        &       [-0,5151]       \\
$\beta_{02}$    &       3,4165  &       3,4766  &       3,4202  &       3,3907  &       3,4769   &      3,4385  &       3,3878  &       3,4341  \\
               &        ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)       &      ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-165,2968]     &       [-116,7258]     &       [125,3916]      &        [-247,8495]    &       [-45,3920]      &       [12,9270]       &       [-114,5733]     \\
$\beta_{112}$   &       -0,0502 &       -0,1331 &       -0,1087 &       0,0127  &       -0,1745  &      -0,0729 &       -0,0437 &       -0,1077 \\
               &        (0,7924)        &       (0,4748)        &       (0,5709)        &       (0,9458)         &      (0,3579)        &       (0,6963)        &       (0,8146)        &       (0,5681)        \\ \hline
               &        [-]     &       [17,9331]       &       [30,9663]       &       [-81,7249]      &        [44,5081]      &       [-53,2645]      &       [-57,1757]      &       [-35,2755]      \\
$\beta_{122}$   &       0,1608  &       0,132   &       0,111   &       0,2923  &       0,0892   &      0,2465  &       0,2528  &       0,2176  \\
               &        (0,5911)        &       (0,6464)        &       (0,7162)        &       (0,3179)         &      (0,7638)        &       (0,3905)        &       (0,3909)        &       (0,4578)        \\\hline
               &        [-]     &       [-13,5716]      &       [31,0160]       &       [100,3102]      &        [6,4886]       &       [74,0291]       &       [149,3235]      &       [115,0191]      \\
$\beta_{22}$    &       -0,1228 &       -0,1395 &       -0,0847 &       0,0004  &       -0,1149  &      -0,0319 &       0,0606  &       0,0184  \\
               &        (0,6843)        &       (0,6469)        &       (0,7761)        &       (0,9989)         &      (0,7040)        &       (0,9125)        &       (0,8249)        &       (0,9481)        \\\hline
              & [-]     &       [39,2112]       &       [-4,8815]       &       [-22,6829]      &        [30,9879]      &       [16,1972]       &       [-31,8051]      &       [0,3957]        \\
$\beta_{312}$   &       -0,2325 &       -0,1413 &       -0,2439 &       -0,2853 &       -0,1605  &      -0,1949 &       -0,3065 &       -0,2316 \\
             &  (0,2806)        &       (0,5029)        &       (0,2570)        &       (0,1804)        &        (0,4553)       &       (0,3623)        &       (0,1471)        &       (0,2847)        \\\hline
             &  [-]     &       [63,3405]       &       [-4,4498]       &       [-64,9917]      &        [54,1403]      &       [0,4386]        &       [-78,0729]      &       [-23,6573]      \\
$\beta_{322}$   &       -0,2052 &       -0,0752 &       -0,2143 &       -0,3385 &       -0,0941  &      -0,2043 &       -0,3654 &       -0,2537 \\
            &   (0,5233)        &       (0,8104)        &       (0,5133)        &       (0,2872)        &        (0,7730)       &       (0,5239)        &       (0,2571)        &       (0,4418)        \\\hline
            &   [-]     &       [59,6874]       &       [1,7870]        &       [-34,0306]      &        [52,7582]      &       [21,7487]       &       [-36,9651]      &       [6,2874]        \\
$\beta_{42}$    &       -0,1673 &       -0,0675 &       -0,1643 &       -0,2243 &       -0,079   &      -0,1309 &       -0,2292 &       -0,1568 \\
           &    (0,3622)        &       (0,7098)        &       (0,3721)        &       (0,2111)        &        (0,6689)       &       (0,4727)        &       (0,1980)        &       (0,3928)        \\\hline
           &    [-]     &       [1,4721]        &       [-8,0926]       &       [-29,5914]      &        [-1,9366]      &       [-20,1763]      &       [-45,0051]      &       [-31,7090]      \\
$\beta_{512}$   &       -0,127  &       -0,1252 &       -0,1373 &       -0,1646 &       -0,1295  &      -0,1527 &       -0,1842 &       -0,1673 \\
           &    (0,3863)        &       (0,3857)        &       (0,3374)        &       (0,2570)        &        (0,3611)       &       (0,2886)        &       (0,1907)        &       (0,2351)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [100,9776]      &       [-25,4129]      &       [10,5148]       &       [65,7938]        &      [95,2973]       &       [-17,8592]      &       [52,6902]       \\
$\beta_{522}$   &       0,3009  &       -0,0029 &       0,3774  &       0,2693  &       0,1029   &      0,0142  &       0,3547  &       0,1424  \\
        &       (0,2084)        &       (0,9904)        &       (0,1105)        &       (0,2515)        &        (0,6821)       &       (0,9538)        &       (0,1248)        &       (0,5706)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [73,3693]       &       [22,6689]       &       [20,0987]       &       [81,5366]        &      [79,7052]       &       [44,7341]       &       [88,3361]       \\
$\beta_{612}$   &       0,1642  &       0,0437  &       0,127   &       0,1312  &       0,0303   &      0,0333  &       0,0907  &       0,0192  \\
        &       (0,6651)        &       (0,9061)        &       (0,7336)        &       (0,7251)        &        (0,9348)       &       (0,9283)        &       (0,8026)        &       (0,9583)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [22,3382]       &       [5,0190]        &       [4,3064]        &       [22,5685]        &      [22,5925]       &       [10,1339]       &       [22,8972]       \\
$\beta_{622}$   &       0,4168  &       0,3237  &       0,3959  &       0,3989  &       0,3228   &      0,3227  &       0,3746  &       0,3214  \\
        &       (0,2509)        &       (0,3606)        &       (0,2684)        &       (0,2650)        &        (0,3629)       &       (0,3627)        &       (0,2828)        &       (0,3607)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [-29,7453]      &       [-10,2254]      &       [50,1416]       &       [-35,2851]       &      [15,1650]       &       [43,0284]       &       [16,0191]       \\
$\beta_{72}$    &       0,1300  &       0,1686  &       0,1433  &       0,0648  &       0,1758   &      0,1103  &       0,0740  &       0,1092  \\
        &       (0,4488)        &       (0,3087)        &       (0,4027)        &       (0,7041)        &        (0,2922)       &       (0,5092)        &       (0,6622)        &       (0,5159)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [100,3907]      &       [22,2708]       &       [-32,6317]      &       [113,4617]       &      [60,5910]       &       [-25,7052]&     [56,5706]       \\
$\beta_{812}$   &       0,0469  &       -0,0002 &       0,0365  &       0,0623  &       -0,0063  &      0,0185  &       0,0590  &       0,0204  \\
        &       (0,7473)        &       (0,9990)        &       (0,8025)        &       (0,6613)        &        (0,9653)       &       (0,8962)        &       (0,6771)        &       (0,8868)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [10,5188]       &       [-26,1467]      &       [69,5096]       &       [-27,8880]       &      [67,4813]       &       [62,8643]       &       [44,2431]       \\
$\beta_{822}$   &       -0,0366 &       -0,0327 &       -0,0461 &       -0,0112 &       -0,0468  &      -0,0119 &       -0,0136 &       -0,0204 \\
        &       (0,8277)        &       (0,8437)        &       (0,7816)        &       (0,9456)        &        (0,7779)       &       (0,9418)        &       (0,9328)        &       (0,8998)        \\
\hline
        &       [-]     &       [476,2726]      &       [-4989,7926]    &       [8406,4907]     &        [-3793,2938]   &       [7532,8037]     &       [4282,1708]     &       [4042,7417]     \\
$\beta_{912}$   &       0,0019  &       -0,007  &       0,0945  &       -0,1542 &       0,0723   &      -0,138  &       -0,0776 &       -0,0732 \\
        &       (0,9897)        &       (0,9607)        &       (0,5258)        &       (0,2789)        &        (0,6241)       &       (0,3322)        &       (0,5849)        &       (0,6095)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [-16,7772]      &       [-33,7041]      &       [0,3092]        &       [-41,4144]       &      [-14,0791]      &       [-38,3522]      &       [-43,4143]      \\
$\beta_{922}$   &       0,2005  &       0,2342  &       0,2681  &       0,1999  &       0,2836   &      0,2287  &       0,2774  &       0,2876  \\
        &       (0,0477)        &       (0,0180)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0455)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0206)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       ($< 0,01$)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [-26,3750]      &       [14,1763]       &       [23,2927]       &       [-12,2019]       &      [-3,3005]       &       [41,6558]       &       [17,4443]       \\
$\beta_{102}$   &       -0,3069 &       -0,3879 &       -0,2634 &       -0,2354 &       -0,3444  &      -0,3171 &       -0,1791 &       -0,2534 \\
        &       (0,0173)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0379)        &       (0,0702)        &       ($< 0,01$)      &       (0,0149)        &       (0,1596)        &       (0,0551)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [162,8640]      &       [-102,1359]     &       [-84,1793]      &       [44,1015]        &      [59,6800]       &       [-199,2437]     &       [-85,6125]      \\
$\beta_{12}$    &       -0,0504 &       0,0317  &       -0,1018 &       -0,0928 &       -0,0282  &      -0,0203 &       -0,1508 &       -0,0935 \\
        &       (0,6016)        &       (0,7544)        &       (0,2903)        &       (0,3263)        &        (0,7857)       &       (0,8420)        &       (0,1051)        &       (0,3596)        \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [2,4220]        &       [-3,4669]       &       [-3,0767]       &       [-1,9391]        &      [-1,3636]       &       [-6,2017]       &       [-5,9081]       \\
$\sigma_1$      &       0,5178  &       0,5052  &       0,5357  &       0,5337  &       0,5278  &        0,5248 &       0,5499  &       0,5484  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [1,8267]        &       [0,9849]        &       [2,0193]        &       [1,4232]         &      [2,2265]        &       [4,1780]        &       [2,9235]        \\
$\sigma_2$      &       0,5452  &       0,5353  &       0,5399  &       0,5342  &       0,5375  &        0,5331 &       0,5225  &       0,5293  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [2,7645]        &       [-4,6144]       &       [-4,0787]       &       [-2,6912]        &      [-1,9713]       &       [-8,6345]       &       [-8,0444]       \\
$\alpha_1$      &       0,4779  &       0,4646  &       0,4999  &       0,4973  &       0,4907  &        0,4873 &       0,5191  &       0,5163  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
        &       [-]     &       [2,2435]        &       [0,8065]        &       [2,3235]        &       [1,4781]         &      [2,6067]        &       [4,3202]        &       [2,9517]        \\
$\alpha_2$      &       0,4377  &       0,4279  &       0,4342  &       0,4275  &       0,4312  &        0,4263 &       0,4188  &       0,4248  \\
        &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)     &       (-)      \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{scriptsize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christian, this is a solution for the first and second page, but the third page say continuação, and I need it say conclusão.I try to do the same you did for the second page, but then the second and third page say conclusão, any idea?

Comment: @MarisolGarcíaPeña: As I said, it's not the solution for the last page

Comment: Please replace `\caption` in the `\endhead` part with `\caption*`

Comment: Thank you again @ChristianHupfer. I hope you or some one else can help me for the header of the third page.

Comment: @MarisolGarcíaPeña: No, not yet. I fear, the easiest solution is a manual split of the table and write `conclusao` expliclity (sorry, I don't have a Brazilean keyboard)

Comment: Ok @ChristianHupfer, I think it is a solution for the moment.